# Expand "How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?" beyond just Windows?

Tags: discussion

Should we expand [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc) to not be limited to just Windows PCs?

It's currently tagged Windows specifically (for example).

I ask because I suspect we're only going to see more questions like these going forward:

- [Removing nav-links malware in Google Chrome on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/651313/removing-nav-links-malware-in-google-chrome-on-os-x)
- https://superuser.com/questions/859023/native-mac-malware-opening-urls-across-all-browsers

Comment: Not sure… even now, that question is almost too broad.

Comment: @slhck I see what you're saying, but I remember it was intended to be sort of broad, to counteract the 1,000,000 "too narrow" "how do I remove virus XYZ" questions it was to replace. :)

Comment: Absolutely. I'm just not experienced enough with malware on OS X and Linux to know whether it would require a completely different approach altogether.

Comment: Hmm, me neither. :) Perhaps de/retag it and put a fat Bounty for an answer more OSX-centric procedure? I'll foot the bounty..